# Facebook login() does not open the auth popup

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Today, all of a sudden, facebook sdk login() stopped showing the popup [in my app](https://gotaguydev.com/sign-in). Even the `getLoginStatus()` is not getting any responses.

Here's how I'm initializing it:

```
// 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'
FB.init({
  appId: facebookId,
  cookie: true,
  xfbml: false,
  version: 'v3.2'
})
```

Strange thing is, if I keep the same sdk config, but change the sdk source to `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/debug.js`, it starts working again `: /`

Ideas?

Comment: Bugs sneak in from time to time, even with a company as big as Facebook … Suggest you go check their bug report section, if anyone has reported something like this recently already, or create a bug report yourself.

Comment: Here's the [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/243689109873545/), for anyone interested.

Comment: `version: 'v4.37'` - what’s that? This is supposed to specify the Graph API version you are using. The latest currently available version is v3.2, so this makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @04FS it's been a while since I set it up. Have totally forgotten where I got it from. Where did you get yours from?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#versioning, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart#loading

Comment: @04FS Same behavior with `v3.2` : /

Comment: Still, should rather update the bug report in that regard, otherwise their first response might probably just be pointing that out as well.

Comment: @04FS yessir. done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was having what sounds like the same issue, and finally just resolved it. I was using the return value of the sdk to reference the FB api:

```
var FB;
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  // api is ready, use the obtained reference to do things
  FB.init({ ... });
}
require(['//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk'], function(result) {
  // API reference from here used to work, and still does using debug.js
  FB = result;
});
```

The returned object has the expected FB.____ functions, but calling them no longer has any effect. Referencing window.FB fixed the issue, more like:

```
var FB;
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  // api is ready
  FB = window.FB;
  FB.init({ ... });
};
require(['//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk']);
```

Hope this helps.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/759583234410860